# Get set of random numbers from input List having fixed sum using C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, random, sum

I am looking for a C# algorithm that would give me a set of random integers from input List, such that the sum of obtained random integers is N.

For example:
If the list is {1,2,3,4,5,6...100} and N is 20, then the algorithm should return a set of random numbers like {5,6,9} or {9,11} or {1,2,3,4,10} etc.

Note that the count of integers in result set need not be fixed. Also, the input list can have duplicate integers. Performance is one of my priority as the input list can be large (around 1000 integers) and I need to randomize about 2-3 times in a single web request. I am flexible with not sticking to List as datatype if there is a performance issue with Lists.

I have tried below method which is very rudimentary and performance inefficient:

1. Use the Random class to get a random index from the input list
2. Get the integer from input list present at index obtained in #1. Lets call this integer X.
3. Sum = Sum + X.
4. Remove X from input list so that it does not get selected next.
5. If Sum is less than required total N, add X to outputList and go back to #1.
6. If the Sum is more than required total N, reinitialize everything and restart the process.
7. If the Sum is equal to required total N, return outputList

   ```
   while(!reachedTotal)
   {
       //Initialize everything
       inputList.AddRange(originalInputList);
       outputList = new List<int>();
       while (!reachedTotal)
       {
           random = r.Next(inputList.Count);
           sum += inputList.ElementAt(random);
           if(sum<N)
           {

               outputList.Add(inputList.ElementAt(random));
               inputList.RemoveAt(random);
           }
           else if(sum>N)
               break;
           else
               reachedTotal = true;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why do you just describe the code you used. Post it also...

Comment: Is the list arbitrary or do you know some of its characteristics (e.g. consists of consecutive numbers)? If it is arbitrary, then the problem is a variation of subset-sum, which is NP-complete.

Comment: is it guaranteed that a solution exists?

Comment: @NicoSchertler - The list is arbitrary.

Comment: @Benj Solution is not guaranteed. But I am fine with 10% variance from total N.

Comment: @L.B -  Added code as per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stochastical approach that gives you a solution within a 10% range of N - Assuming one exists

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflowSnippets
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // The code you are interested in starts below this line
            const Int32 N = 100;
            Int32 nLowerBound = (90 * N) / 100; Int32 nUpperBound = (110 * N) / 100;

            Random rnd = new Random();
            Int32 runningSum = 0;
            Int32 nextIndex = 0;

            List<Int32> inputList = GenerateRandomList( /* entries = */ 1000);
            List<Int32> o = new List<Int32>();

            while (runningSum < nLowerBound)
            {
                nextIndex = rnd.Next(inputList.Count); if (nUpperBound < (runningSum + inputList[nextIndex])) continue;

                runningSum += inputList[nextIndex];
                o.Add(inputList[nextIndex]);
                inputList.RemoveAt(nextIndex);
            }
            // The code you are interested in ends above this line
            // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

            for(Int32 i = 0; i < o.Count;i++)
            {
                if (b.Length != 0) b.Append(",");
                b.Append(o[i].ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Exact N    : " + N);
            Console.WriteLine("Upper Bound: " + nUpperBound);
            Console.WriteLine("Lower Bound: " + nLowerBound);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("sum(" + b.ToString() + ")=" + GetSum(o).ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        #region Helper methods
        private static object GetSum(List<int> o)
        {
            Int32 sum = 0;

            foreach (Int32 i in o) sum += i;

            return sum;
        }
        private static List<Int32> GenerateRandomList(Int32 entries)
        {
            List<Int32> l = new List<Int32>();

            for(Int32 i = 1; i < entries; i++)
            {
                l.Add(i);
            }

            return l;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

1. Forgot to remove the element from the input-list so it cannot be selected twice
2. Fixed the 'remove element' insertion

Comment: Thanks Benj. I made one change to your answer - Add the int to outputList first, and then remove from inputList :)